# Quero fazer o usuário ser obrigado a responder Sim ou Não

Tags: python, while

Estou fazendo um programa onde o usuário digita o valor e o programa escreve ele por extenso. Eu terminei o problema e gostaria de perguntar ao usuário se ele deseja continuar logo ao final, mas não estou conseguindo.

```
cont=('zero', 'um', 'dois', 'três', 'quatro', 'cinco', 'seis', 'sete', 'oito', 'nove', 'dez', 'onze','Doze','Treze','Quatorze','Quinze','Dezesseis','Dezessete','Dezoito','Dezenove','vinte')
c='S'
while c == 'S':
    while True:
        num=int(input('Digite um numero entre 0 e 20: '))
        if 0<=num<=20:
            break
        print('Tente mais uma vez.',end='')
    print(f'Você digitou o numero {cont[num]}')
    while True:
        c=str(input('Deseja continuar? [S/N]: '))
```

Answer (score -4):

isso acontece, pq vc fez um laço (while) que não faz nenhuma comparação, e tem por certo que deve sempre rodar (true).

```
while True: 
     c=str(input('Deseja continuar? [S/N]: '))
```

No entanto, para seu código, ele nem é preciso, pode simplesmente tirar o while e deixar a linha de baixo

```
cont=('zero', 'um', 'dois', 'três', 'quatro', 'cinco', 'seis', 'sete', 'oito', 'nove', 'dez', 'onze','Doze','Treze','Quatorze','Quinze','Dezesseis','Dezessete','Dezoito','Dezenove','vinte')
c='S'
while c == 'S':
    while True:
        num=int(input('Digite um numero entre 0 e 20: '))
        if 0<=num<=20:
            break
        print('Tente mais uma vez.',end='')
    print(f'Você digitou o numero {cont[num]}')
    c=str(input('Deseja continuar? [S/N]: '))
```